# Does reading a TChan result in blocking or polling?

Tags: haskell, ghc, stm

First, some background. I want a queue which I would like to operate in one of two different modes.  In the first mode, I want to be able retrieve an element if one exists in the queue but *not* to block if there is no element.  In the second mode, I want to be able to block until the queue has an element.  (I am aware that I could use a specialized mechanism for each mode, but I'd like to factor out some common code and thus it would be easiest if I could use the same mechanism for both modes of operation.)

I could use `Chan`, but according to the documentation I shouldn't use `isEmptyChan` because it is deprecated due to potential for deadlock.  This leaves me with `TChan`.  The `tryReadTChan` function gives me exactly what I want for the first mode (i.e. I can check whether an element is present without blocking) but I am not sure exactly what `readTChan` does.  My mental model is that the `atomically` block will keep retrying until an element is present in the channel, which means it will busy loop wasting CPU cycles; this is unlike `readChan` (i.e., the non-STM version) which (if I understand correctly) will actually block execution of the thread until an element is available, as MVars are understood by the runtime threads scheduler.

So is `TChan` like `Chan` in that if I use `readTChan` the runtime is smart enough to not schedule the calling thread until a value is available?  Or will it waste a lot of CPU cycles continually polling into a value arrives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

STM blocking (via `retry`) behaves as if it retries the transaction immediately, but the implementation is smarter: Since STM keeps track of what variables you've read as the transaction goes on, it knows that the transaction will behave the same way as long as those variables have the same values. So when a transaction fails, it'll block (won't actually retry) until one of the variables you used has changed. In the case of `TChan`s, that means it'll block until someone writes to the `TChan`.

I recommend Simon Marlow's [slides](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/slides/cadarache2012/) on concurrent and parallel Haskell for a good introduction to STM (among other things).

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot, and in particular for the link to the talk!

Answer (score 11):

Your mental model has the right denotational semantics, but misses out on an operational optimization STM makes. When a transaction retries in STM, it blocks until some `TVar` it read from before the retry is changed. (And yes, `TChan` is implemented in terms of `TVar`.)

So executing a transaction has the same meaning as if the transaction was continually retrying - but the STM system is smart enough to not busy-loop if there's no chance of things going differently within the transaction.